# Virtually memory of created process with ASLR disabled

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, process, virtual-memory

I am trying to understand why the address of stack variables of a given process have different values when the process is executed on its own on the command line and when another process starts the process with an execl call (without forking). I am running these program in an intel 64 bit kali linux machine with ASLR disabled.

Here is the code for the program that has its stack variable address printed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer; 
    printf("buffer: %p\n", &buffer);
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the code for the program that executes the code above without forking:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int var;
    printf("var is at %p\n", &var); 
    execl("./a", "a", NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

Since executing a process in the shell, to my knowledge, is the same as the shell executing an exec after forking itself, I tested having the code above fork itself first then have the child perform an exec. Here is the code for the third experiment:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int var;
    printf("var is at %p\n", &var);
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        execl("./a", "a", NULL);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

All three programs above are compiled with gcc with the options: -fno-stack-protector -z execstack.

Here are the results of the various tests I conducted:

1.) Executing first program on shell:

```
buffer: 0x7fffffffe2df
```

2.) Executing first program on a process using exec (without forking):

```
var is at 0x7fffffffe2dc
buffer: 0x7fffffffe2ef
```

3.) Executing first program on a process using exec (with forking):

```
var is at 0x7fffffffe2cc
buffer: 0x7fffffffe2df
```

I expected that the location of buffer in the first two tests to be the same due to each process supposedly not having an effect on each other's memory. I tested   to see whether the location of global variables changed and sure enough they stayed in the same addresses whatever the test.

To my knowledge, one reason the stack is shifted when a process executes is due to inheriting environment variables from the shell. So I theorize that executing a process by having a different process use execs causes the former to inherit variables located in the stack.

However my third test says otherwise. It simulated how the shell executes a process and it got the same address as executing the process from the shell directly. I expected the result to be the same as my second experiment due to it using the same process context as the second experiment (thus inheriting the same environment) as the second experiment. The only difference was I forked first and had the child execute the exec call.

I would deeply appreciate it If someone can point me to the direction as to why the stack behaves this way.

Comment: Try setting the `LD_SHOW_AUXV=1` environment variable and looking for differences. These show the ELF auxiliary vectors passed to the executable at start up. These vectors, along with the arguments and environment, are pushed on the stack.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that after I get home

Comment: @RossRidge I have tested LD_SHOW_AUXV=1, however they appear to have the same addresses on their vectors. I have also checked the environment variables, they have the same variables only at different addresses. I cannot access the addresses after the environment variables, I can say for certain however that whatever is shifting the stack has to do with the data after the environment variables, those found at higher addresses.